# Insert "suggestions" of Bootstrap typeahead into a selector

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am using the bootstrp "typehead" auto complete widget and i have the following scenario:

### The wanted result:

the `suggestion: Handlebars.comp( tr's.. )` -> will appear in the $('#suggestions') selector

### JS

```
$('#typeahead-1').typeahead({
            hint: true,
            highlight: true,
            minLength: 1
        }, {
            name: 'PriceItems',
            displayKey: 'Name',
            limit: 10,
            minLenght: 1,
            templates: {
                empty: [
                  '<div>',
                    'unable to find any items',
                  '</div>'
                ],
                suggestion: Handlebars.compile("<tr><td>{{Name}}</td><td><span class='popupItem'>CS</span></td><td><span class='popupItem'>S</span></td><td><span class='popupItem'>M</span></td><td><span class='popupItem'>L</span></td><td><span class='popupItem'>XL</span></td></tr>")
            },
            source: function (query, process) {
                jQuery.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/Mapping/FetchData",
                    dataType: "json",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    async: true,
                    success: function (data) {
                        process(data);
                    },
                    failure: function (errMsg) {
                        alert(errMsg);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

### Html

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Type item name..." id="typeahead-1">
      <div>
           <table class='table table-striped dt-responsive dataTable'>
              <tbody id="suggestions"></tbody>
           </table>
     </div>
```

Comment: "the suggestion: Handlebars.comp( tr's.. ) -> will appear in the $('#suggestions') selector" What does this mean? Your question is unclear to me.

Comment: @Stephan Muller what i want is that the table(whole table) will appear under the selector id 'suggestions' -> in the DOM i will see the columns and the rows IN the id 'suggestions'